# Spacing issue for newenvironment wrapper of equation environment

Tags: spacing, equations

If I create a custom environment based on the `equation` environment, I get a spacing issue: the next line of text after my environment closes doesn't start on the left margin.

Example code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\newenvironment{myenv}{\begin{equation}}{\end{equation}}
\noindent $| \leftarrow$ this is the left margin.
\begin{myenv}
e ^{i \pi} + 1 = 0
\end{myenv}
$| \leftarrow$ this isn't the left margin.
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Removing the newline after `\end{myenv}` solves the spacing problem, but the resulting code is not readable.

Of course, in this example I could just use the equation environment itself. My real issue involves a more complex custom environment that suffers from the same problem, and which also includes an equation environment within it.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The `\end{equation}` command terminates display math mode, so TeX resumes horizontal mode and only after this action it sees the end-of-line which follows `\end{myenv}`, processing it as part of the paragraph.

The solution is to append `\ignorespacesafterend` to the "end" part of the environment definition:

```
\newenvironment{myenv}
  {\begin{equation}}
  {\end{equation}\ignorespacesafterend}
```