# newenvironment with displaymath causes strange extra space/indent on following line

Tags: spacing, environments

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Spacing issue for newenvironment wrapper of equation environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/50575/spacing-issue-for-newenvironment-wrapper-of-equation-environment)

I have

```
\newenvironment{mymath}{\begin{displaymath}\begin{array}{l}}{\end{array}\end{displaymath}}
```

but when I write

```
\begin{mymath}
 f(x) = 10
\end{mymath}
and some following text
```

there is an odd piece of horizontal space inserted before `and some following text` that is not there if I just write the begin and end commands for the environments out by hand.

Comment: very similar to [Spacing issue for newenvironment wrapper of equation environment](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/50575/).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

add `\ignorespacesafterend` as the last thing in your end code.