# New equation environment causes indentation in text immediately following the equation

Tags: environments

MWE :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}
\newenvironment{Equation}{\begin{equation*}}{\end{equation*}} 

\begin{document}
\begin{Equation}
x = y
\end{Equation}
The first line of text which follows the equation (in the same paragraph) 
is slightly indented. 
\end{document}
```

Obviously I don't want the indentation.

I'm introducing this new environment because it makes the source code have a nicer color scheme in my LaTeX editor (TeXmaker). Basically I don't want it to recognize the equation environment.

Comment: You know you can also use `\[ math here \]`?

Comment: You should change your editor color scheme instead of doing it from the LaTeX side.

Comment: It still recognizes `\[\]` as a math environment.

Comment: Of course, for it is math. It is a shortcut for `\begin{equation*}`  and the end part. Math is math.

Answer (score 0):

It would be better just to configure your editor colours but:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}
\newenvironment{Equation}{\begin{equation*}}{\end{equation*}\ignorespacesafterend} 

\begin{document}
\begin{Equation}
x = y
\end{Equation}
The first line of text which follows the equation (in the same paragraph) 
is slightly indented. 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Don't we have a duplicate for that?

Comment: I agree but I don't think it's possible to reconfigure the colors in a suitable way with TeXmaker.

Comment: quite possibly do you have one to suggest?

Comment: @RandyRanderson the only thing I know about texmaker is that it isn't emacs but it would seem strange if the colours are not configurable, if only for accessibility reasons.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/50575/spacing-issue-for-newenvironment-wrapper-of-equation-environment/50581#50581

Comment: You can change the colors but you can't change the fact that inline equations within a displayed equation disrupt the color scheme.